# Jenkins rebuild with same parameters but new build number

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have a Jenkins job that is parameterized that we run every night for our testing. We'd like to be able to check the results of this build in Jenkins in the morning via either the Downstream Build View, or the Build Pipeline View, as we want to see which sub-components passed and failed.

The problem is, we also sometimes run this build manually in the morning using the rebuild button so that we get the same parameters. When this happens, the previous nightly build seems to get overridden with the results of the new build. If someone runs a sub-job with the rebuild button, that sub-job and it's children's results from the previous nightly build now show as the newest run.

I've been looking into the rebuild plugin and how it works, but I can't find this answer. Does re-building always build on top of a previous build, or is there some way to re-build with the same parameters, but to give the new build a unique build number so as to preserve the results of the previous run?

Basically what I'm looking for is "New build with same parameters as the old build" instead of "Re-run the old build". Any help you could give would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rebuild Plugin always starts a new build (but keeps the old parameteters , although you're able to edit them before the build starts). This means that a new $BUILD_NUMBER is set.

Comment: Do you know why then that the run under the old build number is updated and in our list of builds no new build appears? What you describe is the desired behavior, but not what we are seeing.

Comment: That's strange because here (aka: "Rebuilder" Version 1.31 ) is that exactly the behavior we're experiencing.
Another approach could be to create a helper job that parses the last job (JENKINS_URL:PORT/job/JOBNAME/BUILD_NUMBER/api/xml for example) and starts your main jenkins job with the parsed parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it sets a new build number for the next build . You should be , however, be able to edit or keep the same parameters imo.